# Two form input values can not be the same Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form that takes two separate input strings Origin and Destination. Origin and Destination can not have the same value and an error is need when this is the case. I'm using Ruby on Rails 5. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean by taking multiple values from select input tag in the form ?

Comment: please post your code snippet. we cant help you without looking at your initial effort

Answer (score 1):

In your model where origin and destination is located.

```
validate :location_diversity

def location_diversity
  self.errors.add(:origin, message: "can't be the same as destination") if origin == destination
end
```

On save this checks runs the method `:location_diversity` and adds an error in case they are the same. And your controller returns a `422` with the error message.

If you want to check on html/js side without involving the backend:

```
var origin = document.getElementById("origin").value;
var destination = document.getElementById("destination").value;

if (origin === destination) {
  // show error in some <span>
  // and disable the save/sent/whatever button 
}
```